# Get entire html page as response with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am doing an Ajax post to a specific page where I either can get an ID as response if everything went as expected or I could get a random html page and a http 400 as response if something went wrong. In the error case I want to open up the entire html page in a new window. I have tried the following but it is not working - it sets the variable data to [object Object] instead of the intended html page.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: postUrl,
    data:'message=' + message + '&' + 'title=' + title,
    statusCode: {
            400:function(data) {
                var newWin = open('','windowName','height=300,width=300');
                newWin.document.write(data);
        },
    },
    success: function(json) {
        alert("Post success");
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Error connecting to page.");
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't think I knew you could set different status code callbacks for JQuery like that. That's pretty useful!

Comment: Your question isn't very clear.  You would like a redirect to another page in the error postback that you PASS html to?  If so...why?  Just write a static page and call it.  I don't understand what it is you are exactly trying to achieve and the code doesn't appear to be attempting what you are (I think) explaining.

Answer (score 3):

Specify `dataType : 'html'` and change the success function variable. Example:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'html',
    url: postUrl,
    data:'message=' + message + '&' + 'title=' + title,
    statusCode: {
            400:function(data) {
                var newWin = open('','windowName','height=300,width=300');
                newWin.document.write(data);
        },
    },
    success: function(html) {
        alert("Post success");
        $("#myDiv").html(html);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Error connecting to page.");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but that isn't really helping me... I want the new window to include the html page - the window I open when receiving http 400 response.

Comment: if you want to "open a new window" instance, as in a new browser window, use window.open()

Comment: @AndréHegge HTML in a JS `alert` will not parse, and will look like `<!doctype html><head>...`. You may want to use a dialog, such as the one from jQuery UI: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/